# Why does a git push on any Project trigger a build in Google Cloud Build (GitHub Apps)?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I want to enable the [Google Cloud Build](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) Github App in several Github projects.

1. So on the [Google Cloud Build](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) Github App, I click on [grant this app access to your GitHub account](https://github.com/apps/google-cloud-build/installations/new/permissions?target_id=695120)

[image]

2. Then on the following screen, I install Google Cloud Build on **All repositories**.

[image]

3. Then I'm redirecting to a couple of Google Authorization screens.
4. Then I endup on the Google following screen, where I select an existing Google project-id then accept the consent screen.

[image]

The issue is: a git push on any of my Github repo triggers a build in this google project-id (and not on his related Google project-id)

[image]

Of course I want

- a push in Github project#1 to trigger a build in Google Cloud Build project#1
- a push in Github project#2 to trigger a build in Google Cloud Build project#2

Answer (score 2):

There is now an "Add another project" button that allows you to connect repositories directly to different projects when setting up the Google Cloud Build connection.

See this screenshot:

[image: Add another project]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because the app works on the Account level and not on the project level.