# Cloud Build GitHub App bound to only one GCP Project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

With the [Cloud Build GitHub App](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/support)) I'm trying to have

- *GitHub Repo A* deploy to *GCP Project A*
- *GitHub Repo B* deploy to *GCP Project B*

There is no way to define a target GCP project and it always publishes to the first project. I don't have the rep to further [Freddy Boucher's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478742/why-does-a-git-push-on-any-project-trigger-a-build-in-google-cloud-build-github).